# Conditional (category / subcategories) options in Meteor AutoForm

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I'm currently using autoform and collection2 to generate forms. I would like to create a select option that changes the sub category options.

**eg. Select (category)**
- fruit
- vegetables

**eg. Select (sub-category appears)**

*If fruit selected:*

- apples
- banana

*If vegetables selected:*

- carrot
- broccoli

I've been searching for a solution but I can't find one that works. Can someone please point me in the right direction as I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the current value of `category` by using **[`AutoForm.getFieldValue(fieldName, [formId])`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/api.md#autoformgetfieldvaluefieldname-formidclient)**. Then, you could [set the subcategory options](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#calculate-options-in-the-schema) depending on whether `fruit` or `vegetables` has been selected.

For example:

```
var fruitArr = ['apple', 'banana'];
var vegetablesArr = ['carrot', 'broccoli'];

Food = new Mongo.Collection("food");

Food.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        label: "Category",
        allowedValues: ['fruit', 'vegetables']
    },
    subcategory: {
        type: String,
        label: "Subcategory",
        allowedValues: _.union(fruitArr, vegetablesArr),
        autoform: {
            options: function () {
                let category = AutoForm.getFieldValue("category");
                if (!category) return [{label: "Please select a category first", value: ""}];
                if (category === "fruit") return _.map(fruitArr, (v, i) => ({
                    label: "Fruit " + (i + 1) + ": " + v,
                    value: v
                }));
                else return _.map(vegetablesArr, (v, i) => ({label: "Vegetables " + (i + 1) + ": " + v, value: v}));
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to implement it however I'm getting `undefined` for `AutoForm.getFieldValue(fieldName, [formId])`. The form is `collection="Meteor.users'` `id="userProfile"` so I've tried a number of variations with no luck. The last one I tried in the console was `AutoForm.getFieldValue(profile.category, [userProfile]);` Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @bp123 As the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/api.md#autoformgetfieldvaluefieldname-formidclient) states, the function arguments must be passed as Strings. As a result, `AutoForm.getFieldValue("profile.category", "userProfile");` should work.

Comment: Ok this is sort of working except subcategory doesn't update on selection. I've reposed it with the templatet I'm using to see if I can get a fix quick. If you can spot the error let me know. Thanks Matthias hopefully this will work.

Comment: @bp123 I submitted an answer to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074418/select-category-not-updating-sub-category/36077749#36077749).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!