# Select category not updating sub category

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

This is suppose to look at the users category selection and then update the subcategory. The solution was recommended by someone else but I can't seem to get it to work. When I select the category, subcategory doesn't update. Can someone let me know what I'm missing.

Path: `category.js`

```
<template name="category">
    {{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" id="categoryForm" doc=currentUser type="update"}}
        {{> afQuickField name='profile.categories'}}
    {{/autoForm}}   
</template>
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
var fruitArr = ['apple', 'banana'];
var vegetablesArr = ['carrot', 'broccoli'];

Schema.Category = new SimpleSchema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        label: "Category",
        allowedValues: ['fruit', 'vegetables']
    },
    subcategory: {
        type: String,
        label: "Subcategory",
        allowedValues: _.union(fruitArr, vegetablesArr),
        autoform: {
            options: function () {
                let category = AutoForm.getFieldValue("category");
                if (!category) return [{label: "Please select a category first", value: ""}];

                if (category === "fruit") return _.map(fruitArr, (v, i) => ({
                    label: "Fruit " + (i + 1) + ": " + v,
                    value: v
                }));
                else return _.map(vegetablesArr, (v, i) => ({label: "Vegetables " + (i + 1) + ": " + v, value: v}));
            }
        }
    }
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    categories: {
        type: Schema.Category,
        optional: true,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `AutoForm.getFormValues('categoryForm');` in the browser's console log, the following result will be returned:

```
{
   "insertDoc":{
      "profile":{
         "categories":{
            "category":"fruit"
         }
      }
   },
   "updateDoc":{
      "$set":{
         "profile.categories.category":"fruit"
      },
      "$unset":{
         "profile.categories.subcategory":""
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see from above, the schema field `subcategory` is referenced as `profile.categories.subcategory`. Therefore, the field `subcategory` won't be updated because `AutoForm.getFieldValue("category");` returns `undefined`.

You can fix this error by changing

```
let category = AutoForm.getFieldValue("category");
```

to

```
let category = AutoForm.getFieldValue("profile.categories.category");
```

inside your `options` function in the `subcategory` schema field.